# How to show only posts with images?

Tags: images, query, frontpage

I want to hide posts without images on the front page, so I need get an array of ids of those posts.

I know how hide posts on the home page by id, but I need to show only posts with images. This is what I have already:

```
function exclude_post($query) {

  if ($query->is_home)  {
      $query->set('post__not_in', array(1,2) );
  } 
    return $query; 
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','exclude_post');
```

Comment: You mean you want only posts with thumbnails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for post IDs what has no thumbnail. Use meta query to get only those what has thumbnail.

Add meta query

```
function get_only_posts_with_images( $query ) {

  if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )  {
      $query->set( 'meta_query', array( array( 'key' => '_thumbnail_id' ) ) );
  }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_only_posts_with_images' );
```

Or use custom query.

```
$query = "
  SELECT posts.* 
  FROM $wpdb->posts AS posts
  INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts AS attachment 
    ON attachment.`post_parent`=posts.`ID` 
      AND attachment.`post_type`='attachment' 
  WHERE posts.`post_type`='post'
";

$posts_with_images = $wpdb->get_results( $query, OBJECT );
```

Comment: thanks i used meta query, but after if i open single post, image is not shown. In front page ok, but if open any post, image doesn't show. I am new in wordpress, maybe its because array( 'key' => '_thumbnail_id' ) ?

Comment: No, it's not because of that. Try to see if your template even shows thumbnails on single post and debug it a little.

Comment: Great approach ( with `pre_get_posts` ). I have altered your code to include the main query check otherwise all custom queries on the home page will be altered too

Comment: See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/187952/31545) on how to use `pre_get_posts` correctly :-)

Comment: That is great answer and explanation. Edited my code accordingly.