# Custom Post Loop in Archive returns same the_permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I've got the following code that is meant to grab the latest post from each of the provided custom post types (`$customTypes`), it works on the majority of pages of my site, eg here: http://trulycode.com/ - Notice on the right the grey/yellow/blue boxes showing the latest post from the 3 post types.

However on archive pages it shows the same post on each of the 3 boxes, eg see the difference in the sidebar here:
http://trulycode.com/php/ - All of which are currently linking to the same [Apple Watch Review](http://trulycode.com/apple-watch-is-it-really-worth-it/) post.

I've tried wp_reset_postdata() and wp_reset_query(), both of which did nothing.
Any ideas why it's doing this just for the archive.php template page?

```
<div class="three columns">
<?php
$customTypes = array('videos','Downloads','Bytes');
foreach ($customTypes as $key=>$value) {
  $args = array( 'post_type' => $value, 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ($loop->have_posts()) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
      $loop->the_post();
  ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blocky-linker">
      <?php
      if ($key == 0) {
        echo '<div class="blocky blocky--dark wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1.'.$key.'s">';
      } elseif ($key == 1) {
        echo '<div class="blocky blocky--yellow wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1s"data-wow-delay="1.'.$key.'s">';
      } else {
        echo '<div class="blocky blocky--blue wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1s"data-wow-delay="1.'.$key.'s">';
      }
      ?>
        <h3>Latest <?= $value ?></h3>
        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
          the_post_thumbnail();
        }
        ?>
        <h6><?php the_title(); ?> &rarr;</h6>
      </div>
    </a>
  <?php
    endwhile;
  endif;
}
?>

</div>
```

Comment: In my opinion, you have custom filter like`pre_get_posts`  that is not properly used that is changing your custom queries on your archive pages.

Comment: @PieterGoosen - thanks, please see my response, I managed to get it working thanks to your hint :)! - MrWigster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extention to your answer. Your `pre_get_posts` action has a few flaws

```
function add_custom_types_to_tax( $query ) {
  if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    // Get all your post types
    $post_types = get_post_types();

    $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
    return $query;
  }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_types_to_tax' );
```

- `is_category()` and `is_tag()` should be properties to `$query`
- There is not real benefit in checking whether `suppress_filters` is true or false. The main query is always set to to true unless set otherwise by `pre_get_posts`
- `pre_get_posts` is an action, not a filter
- Actions do not need to be returned.
- `pre_get_posts` alters all instances of `WP_Query` ( the main query also uses `WP_Query`), front end and backend. You should always use `is_main_query()` to target the main query only, and also use `!is_admin()` to only target the front end ( this check is not necessary on the home page )

Your code should look something like this

```
function add_custom_types_to_tax( $query ) {
  if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() || $query->is_tag() ) {
    // Get all your post types
    $post_types = get_post_types();

    $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_types_to_tax' );
```

This should solve your issue without any further code needed

### ADDITIONAL NOTES:

- [`get_post_types()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) in the current state you are using it, it returns **all** registered post types including revisions and nav menu items. You would want to look at [`build_in` parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types#Parameters) to exclude all build in types and just return custom post types.
- For non paginated custom queries, use `get_posts` or add the following two parameters to `WP_Query`

  - `'suppress_filters' => true` This will inhibit all filters from altering your custom query.
  - '`no_found_rows' => true'` This will get the desired amount of posts and immediatly bail out. Default behavior of `WP_Query` is to look for **all** posts matching the query in order to count the posts for pagination purposes. This wastes time. Setting `no_found_rows` to `true`, `WP_Query` skips this process. If it hit the desired amount of posts, it immediately stops execution of the query and returns the posts. This saves execution time, making the query faster.

(***NOTE:*** `get_posts()` uses `WP_Query` with these two parameters already set accordingly. That is why `get_posts` cannot be sanely paged and why `get_posts` is not altered by filters)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by @Pieter Goosen advising it was probably something to do with `pre_get_posts`. I had a play around and certainlty it seems to have been the problem. This was my old code:

**Old Code**

```
function add_custom_types_to_tax( $query ) {
  if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    // Get all your post types
    $post_types = get_post_types();

    $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
    return $query;
  }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_types_to_tax' );
```

And I replaced it with this code below, which seems to have solved my problem. On archive pages (eg: http://trulycode.com/php/) the side boxes now show the first post from each custom post type.

**Working code:**

```
function custom_post_archive($query) {
    if ($query->is_archive){
      $post_types = get_post_types();
      $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
    }
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_archive' );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_archive');
```